# Как создать Procfile для Heroku

Tags: heroku

Создал Procfile.txt , но для Heroku это неверный формат, файл должен быть без расширений. Как его создать правильно?

Comment: выбрать переименовать и удалить расширение

Answer (score 0):

Легче всего это сделать через Visual Studio Code. Там можно создать файл Procfile без расширения.